# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n {x+k \choose k} = {x+n+1 \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {x+k \choose k} = {x+n+1 \choose n}$$

I have tried developing right side then induction but I haven’t reached anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn’t answer anything.

Comment: Write the binomial formula for the right-hand side. That should give you an idea for the induction step.

Comment: I solved it, thanks